# Can't import mesh in Gazebo world

Tags: ros, gazebo-11, mesh, gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a custom rospackage to spawn custom meshed models in Gazebo. The package name is `person_sim`. The file structure of the package is as following,

```
person_sim
  |->launch->environment.launch
  |->materials->...
  |->meshes-> my_mesh.world, standing.dae
  |->CMakeLists.txt
  |->package.xml
```

I have a custom world file which includes a mesh as `model` in the `my_mesh.world` file. The `my_mesh.world` file is as following,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <model name="my_mesh">
      <pose>0 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://standing.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I order to check whether the mesh is working properly, I ran the following command which clearly shows the mesh in the gazebo environment.

```
$ roscd person_sim/meshes
$ gazebo my_mesh.world
```

The figure below shows what I see after running the above commands.

[image: image description]

But when I am trying to launch this `my_mesh.world` through roslaunch file, I do not the see the model corresponding to the mesh `standing.dae` at all. The roslaunch file named `environment.launch` that I am using is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find person_sim)/meshes/my_mesh.world"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

The figure below shows that no mesh model is in the gazebo world however the model named `my_mesh` is listed under Gazebo's UI panel on the left. Any help in resolving the issue will be appreciated.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27314/can%27t-import-mesh-in-gazebo-world/) by [Anirban Sinha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/53017/anirban-sinha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think with `<uri>file://standing.dae</uri>`, gazebo will try to look for the file `standing.dae` at your current directory, and the `$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. So, when you run your world file, you are in the same directory as the mesh file, and therefore it can be loaded. However when you run the ROS launch file, I think you are in the different directory, and Gazebo can't find the `standing.dae` file. (You can confirm this by adding `verbose` option when running the ROS script. If it says the file can't be found then that's the point.)

A quick fix would be adding the path to your mesh file to the `$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` by running

```
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH:/path/to/person_sim/meshes
```

and the launch file should load the mesh. However it's probably not the best way.

You can create a model, put your mesh file into the meshes folder of that model, and add an SDF file to load the mesh using `<uri>model://meshes/standing.dae</uri>`, like other models you can find on Gazebo model server.

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2021-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirban Sinha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/53017/anirban-sinha/) on 2021-08-31**:
Adding the mesh directory to the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` solves the problem. Thank you.